# How to properly handle a reverse relationship with the same name

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have a situation where there are multiple pieces with the same field. However, when going with the reverse relationship, it becomes a problem because they cannot seem to coexist:

```
{
  name: '_relatedPeople',
  type: 'joinByArrayReverse',
  withType: 'organization',
  filters: {
    projection: {
      _url: 1,
      title: 1,
      tags: 1
    }
  },
},
{
  name: '_relatedPeople',
  type: 'joinByArrayReverse',
  withType: 'event',
  filters: {
    projection: {
      _url: 1,
      title: 1,
      tags: 1
    }
  },
},
```

The event type overwrites the organization type. Here is the field that both those types have (for DRY):

```
{
  "label": "Related People",
  "help": "",
  "name": "_relatedPeople",
  "type": "joinByArray",
  "withType": ["person"],
  "filters": {
    "projection": {
      "_url": 1,
      "title": 1
    }
  }
}
```

I tried using `idsField` and `reverseOf`, and both failed miserably. What is the appropriate strategy for the person type to be able to get the reverse relationship of the other two types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer by trial and error while sifting through the ApostropheCMS doc. I thought I'd share my solution here, in case others stumble on the same type of issue:

```
{
  name: '_organizations', // type from which to get the pieces, prefixed with "_" and suffixed with "s"
  reverseOf: '_relatedPeople', // field name from which to get the pieces
  type: 'joinByArrayReverse',
  withType: 'organization', // type which holds the pieces
  filters: {
    projection: {
      _url: 1,
      title: 1
    }
  },
},
{
  name: '_events', // type from which to get the pieces, prefixed with "_" and suffixed with "s"
  reverseOf: '_relatedPeople', // field name from which to get the pieces
  type: 'joinByArrayReverse',
  withType: 'event', // type which holds the pieces
  filters: {
    projection: {
      _url: 1,
      title: 1
    }
  },
},
```

Note the `name`, `reverseOf`, and `withType` properties, which is how you can ensure to avoid overwriting the results.

It is then possible to use `data.piece._organizations` and `data.piece._events` and get the `_relatedPeople` for each.